# Firebase signInWithPhoneNumber andIonic

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

Does anyone know how to use the method: `signInWithPhoneNumber` in ionic ?

It works in HTML browsers (using a `reCaptcha`) but not in mobiles operation systems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just finishing to apply a workaround for myself and an application and it seems to work like a charm.

Due to Recaptcha issues you cannot, for now, use ionic with firebase and phone authentication on mobile device from within your application.

You will need a website, and a deeplinking package.

1 - Add a link in your application opening a tab. 
2 - Make your login/signin process there and then redirect the user in your application with deeplinking and passing the informations you need. (verificarionId+ " " + code)
3 - Inside your mobile application extract those strings and log in with credentials.
Happy coding